# Unable to get ID of clicked button with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, click, vuetify.js

Markup:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app dark>
    <v-btn id="test" @click="clickMe">
      Click me
    </v-btn>   
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Script:

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    clickMe(e) {
      alert(e.target.id);
    },
  },
});
```

My expectation is that clicking the button with the ID `test` would trigger the `clickMe` function, get the target ID (`test`), and alert it. Instead, I just get an empty alert window. Can someone explain where my code is failing?

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/f96retyv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely want `currentTarget` instead of `target`. It looks like `Vuetify` wraps your content in a `<div>` for whatever reason so `target` is actually that (since it's the element that initiated the event on the `button`). `currentTarget` will always give you the element the event listener is attached to.

[image]